# Working with glyphs from multiple documents to rearrange a PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, inkscape, ghostscript, embedded-fonts

I am doing some editing on an old PDF comprising vector text and math formulae. Precisely I am extracting one of the problems of an exam paper, so after extracting the corresponding pages, I still need to remove some content before the problem on the first page and after it on the last page.

This leads me to shift content up, and from a page to another. Currently I am doing this shifting with Inkscape. Inkscape lets me open the different pages in as many documents. I use the Poppler/Cairo import because the internal import system does not render the text correctly.

With this, everything works nicely as long as I remain on one single document (page). But when moving contents from a page to another, the pasted content is unusable, it seems because of broken glyph references.

So I resorted to converting all text to curves in my original PDF with `gs -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite in.pdf out.pdf`, then doing the above. This works but gives understandably large PDF files in the end, after reassembling the SVG files with `rsvg-convert -f pdf -o final.pdf page*.svg`.

The nicest thing I think would be not to destroy the glyphs but to have Inkscape convert glyph tables on copy and paste or use a common glyph table for all the pages extracted from the same PDF file.

How can I achieve this ? Or maybe there is a better workflow ? I would like not to rasterize the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correclty,

1. you're opening each page of the original PDF in a separate Inkscape
   window,
2. the problem is a bug when copy-pasting imported content from one Inkscape window to another.

You can remove the 2nd step by changing the 1st. Import both (or more if needed?) consecutive pages of the original PDF into a single Inkscape window, and rearrange using click-and-drag, group and align, or editing the coordinates that appear in the toolbar.

PS: You may also consider using latex with pdfpages package to include trimmed/clipped parts of the original PDF into a latex document. See http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the PDF Import feature. To my dismay preserving the glyphs does not significantly reduce the size of the final document : my 3-page extract still weighs 1.3Mo when the original 24-page document is 460 ko…

Comment: Have you tried `pdfpages` ? Of course it does involve a little more of guesswork to get the clipping values right at first.